# Connect to Redis or MongoDB in DBeaver

Tags: mongodb, redis, dbeaver

There is a very good SQL client solution for Linux users [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/).
 In spec, it is said that it supports MongoDB and Redis databases.
However, there are no such drivers in "New connection" window. 
Does anyone know how to connect to Mongo or Redis?

[image: "New Connection" window]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Enterprise edition has MongoDB and Redis support.

[EE download](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/enterprise/)

> We have split standalone version on Community and Enterprise editions.
>   Community edition includes the same extensions as DBeaver 2.x.
>   Enterprise edition = Community edition + NoSQL support (Cassandra and
>   MongoDB in 3.0). Both Community and Enterprise editions are free and
>   open source. New Cassandra and MongoDB extensions are not open source
>   (but free to use).

[image: MongoDB Connection]

[image: Redis Connection]

Comment: It's been 2 years since the original post and things may have changed. It looks like the enterprise version is not free anymore. They have a 2 week trial but you'll need to buy a license after that.

Comment: The paid version with Mongo support Is called DBeaver Pro now.

Answer (score 11):

Since the EE edition of DBeaver is no longer free you can use [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass) if you want a GUI utility for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [RedisInsight](https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight) (from Redis self) or the popular [AnotherRedisDesktopManager](https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager) for Redis.